# What is the wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 sql tables calls category, movies, category_movies. category and movies tables have many to many relationship. Thats why I use category_movies table. This is tables' structure...

> ```
> Category : cat_id, cat_name, 
> movies : mov_id, mov_name, 
> category_movies : cat_id, mov_id
> ```

Now I have got 3 category IDs dynamically and now I want to select movies' names alone with category names which belongs to 3 category_id have already got.

This is the query that I tried so far..

```
SELECT  c.cat_name AS cn, m.mov_name AS mn, m.mov_id 
FROM    category AS c 
        INNER JOIN category_movies AS cm ON cm.cat_id = c.cat_id        
        INNER JOIN movies AS m ON m.mov_id = cs.mov_id
WHERE   c.cat_id IN (2, 5, 7)
GROUP BY c.cat_name, m.mov_name, m.mov_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

but this is now working.. can anybody tell me what is wrong with this query?

Comment: not "INNOR JOIN " it should be "INNER JOIN "

Comment: How do you expect anything to be returned when you are restricting the records with this?

`WHERE cat_id = 2 AND 5 AND 7` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `IN` clause on this

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE cat_id IN (2, 5, 7)
```

and is the same with

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE cat_id = 2 OR
      cat_id = 5 OR
      cat_id = 7
```

Please also take note that it is `INNER JOIN` not `INNOR JOIN`

but I guess, you want to perform `RELATIONAL Division` (*you want to search for a movie that has all the category you want to find*)

```
SELECT  c.cat_name, m.mov_name, m.mov_id 
FROM    category AS c 
        INNER JOIN movies AS m ON m.cat_id = c.cat_id
        INNER JOIN category_movies AS cm ON cm.mov_id = m.mov_id
WHERE   cat_id IN (2, 5, 7)
GROUP BY c.cat_name, m.mov_name, m.mov_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

- [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Great! about finding mistakes of others

Comment: without this two line query is working.. but with this lines its now working.. GROUP BY c.cat_name, m.mov_name, m.mov_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3

Comment: whole query give me an empty set

Comment: nevermind about the `Relational Division` if you don't to. what do you mean empty set? can add sample records?

Comment: Empty set (0.01 sec) from mysql client

Comment: what query did you execute? can you post it? `:D`

Comment: @TharangaNuwan so you use the query of `Relational Division`, get rid of `GROUP BY c.cat_name, m.mov_name, m.mov_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3` if you want to show records where it will match to atleast one of the condition in the `where` clause, what the query will do is to select only those records where the `cat_id` has all the values on it, `2, 5, 7` specifically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22590/discussion-between-tharanga-nuwan-and-jw)

Answer (score 0):

INNOR -> INNER
WHERE cat_id = 2 AND 5 AND 7

that hardly can be right it probably should be OR

Answer (score 0):

1 code

```
SELECT Id, name, YEAR(BillingYar) AS Year
FROM Records
WHERE Year ≥ 2010
```

2 code

```
 SELECT id, name
    FROM students
    WHERE grades = (SELECT MAX(grades)
                    FROM students
                    GROUP BY subject_id);
```

I can see only in first code wrong this symbol ( ≥ ), need to be >= . Something else?